# Find Spring Batch job executions filtered and ordered by execution date

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement to search Spring Batch job executions using the following search filters and result ordering: name, exit status, start date, end date.

The JobExplorer API is pretty thin, and using only findJobInstancesByJobName and getJobExecutions means getting the whole set of job executions in memory (500.000+), and then filtering/ordering and returning a page of 25, which is out of the question.

Apart from doing native queries on Spring Batch tables directly, is there any other way of searching the job executions?

---

EDIT 1:

So far I have the following code:

```
    List<JobExecution> findJobExecutions(String jobName, ExitStatus status, Date start, Date end){
            // How to filter by status, and date without getting all in memory?

            int startRow = 0;
            int count = 100000;

            List<JobInstance> instances = jobExplorer.findJobInstancesByJobName(jobName, startRow, count);
            List<JobExecution> result = instances.stream().map(jobExplorer::getJobExecutions).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

SimpleJobExplorer [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/support/SimpleJobExplorer.html)

Answer (score -1):

**Two Options**

1. You can [Spring Batch Admin console](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/reference.xhtml) for your Job Monitoring and  Job Execution status.For installation and usage you can refer the above link.
2. You can create custom Web Application to monitor your Job Execution status. For this effective usage, it is recommended to usage the spring-batch tables and schema which is given in their [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html#recommendationsForIndexingMetaDataTables).

Comment: 1. Spring Batch Admin does not offer the possibility to search using the specified criteria, or at least I wasn't able to find a web page/json service that offers searching all jobs that have been run on X date.
2. I have a custom web application. The problem is how do I call the existing API: JobExplorer, JobRepository, JobInstanceDao or any other class to be able to search using the above criteria.

Comment: Have you used Spring-batch tables?

Comment: I have Spring Batch tables, but I would like to avoid, if possible, doing native queries on those tables. That would make my code depend on the version of spring batch (maybe they change a column name, for example). But that is surely an option.